# Dailymotion API get id uploaded

Tags: json, dailymotion-api

I'm using the Dailymotion API for upload video form my website.

I have this query :

```
DM.api('/videos','post',{
        url: JSON.parse(xhr.response).url,
        title: $('#title').val(),
        tags: $('#tags').val(),
        channel: $('#channel option:selected').val(),
        published: 'true',
        private: true
    }
);
```

This query return a JSON with the identifier of this upload (I can see this json in my console), but how can I retrieve this json into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

this is rather a javascript question than a dailymotion-api question :)

The dailymotion SDK returns json. Try the following to retrieve the id:

```
DM.api('/videos',
        'post',
        {
            url: JSON.parse(xhr.response).url,
            title: $('#title').val(),
            tags: $('#tags').val(),
            channel: $('#channel option:selected').val(),
            published: 'true',
            private: true 
        },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response.id);
        }
);
```